# "App\Entity\User" object not found by "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver"

Tags: symfony6

Bonjour, je viens de débuter symfony, depuis un moment j'ai cette erreur quand j'essaie d'accéder à une route qui fais appel à l'entité ''User''
Exemple: la route 'login' ou 'register'.

le chemin de l'entité est correcte dans 'security.yaml': voici un aperçus du fichier en question:  providers:
# used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
app_user_provider:
id: App\Security\UserProvider
# used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
firewalls:
dev:
pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
security: false
main:
lazy: true
provider: app_user_provider
# custom_authenticator: App\Security\UserProvider
logout:
path: app_logout